# Bootstrap 4.6 - Add Custom Grid Breakpoints Error

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, node-sass

Trying to add some custom grid breakpoints to my project. According to the bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/), all I need to do is override these SASS variables

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  // Extra small screen / phone
  xs: 0px,
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576px,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768px,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992px,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1400px
);
//
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
);
```

But I'm seeing this error when trying to compile the changes.

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webpack/site/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

      %responsive-container-#{$breakpoint} {
     ^
      You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
From "@extend %responsive-container-xl" on line 30 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss
```

Any idea what might cause this?

Tried instructions indicated by the bootstrap documentation.

Comment: what did you change those variables too. and did you recompile?

Comment: I did recompile. The values you see in the post are the new values for said variables. The bootstrap documentation states that I should be able to override the default values by just assigning new values to them.